# Difference between a module and a repository

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

In a cvs repository I am accessing repository & modules. The setup is a little confusing to me, using TortoiseCVS it specifies:

```
repository: corp_root/corp1/
module: geo/GeoReporting          # Notice the "geo/" first.

repository: corp_root/corp2/
module: EmployeeReporting         # Just a single name.
```

It makes sense to me that the first one should be:

```
repository: corp_root/corp1/geo   # Put the "geo" here
module: GeoReporting
```

Is there a good reason this CVS is set up this way, or would a better way would be the last one I listed?